# Spring JMS injection causing application not to startup

Tags: spring, jmstemplate

We have a spring application that publishes and listens to queues on a remote application server.  My publisher and listener which are spring based listen within our own application server.

One of the problems we have for our test environments is the other app. server is not up so when our test application goes to start and it tries to inject JmsTemplate with its **connectionFactory** it blows up because it is not a valid connection and our entire application fails to load.  This is causing grief with the other developers in our group that have nothing to do with JMS.  All they want to do is run and test their code but the **JmsTemplate** connectionFactory is down.

Does anyone have any suggestion for enabling spring ignore some bad injections which will allow our application to start properly?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be achieved by defining separate spring profiles and then passing it as a parameter in your test environments while starting your application. You could mock or ignore any beans then.
Example

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
@Profile("test")
public class AppConfigTest {

....
....
}
```

JVM param / System property

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=test
```